# Getting syntax error my code

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the code below, where I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list });

tb = Ext.getCmp('head-toolbar');
    tb.add({
        text: 'Export',
        menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Export',
                    handler: function() {
                        alert('test');
                    }
                }
                ]
            });
        });
```

Can anyone spot where the error is ?

Comment: Replace second to last `});` with `})`.

Answer (score 1):

A correct but incomplete answer was here, but deleted, so here's a CW reiterating and expanding on it:

You want to remove the `;` indicated:

```
tb = Ext.getCmp('head-toolbar');
tb.add({
    text: 'Export',
    menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Export',
                handler: function () {
                    alert('test');
                }
            }
        ]
    }) // <== Don't put a ; here
});
```

You do that because a semicolon ends a statement, but you're still within your outermost object initializer (the one you're passing into `add`), so you're not ending a statement there. Doing so is a syntax error.